Apache Nifi Expression Language: find part of content, which matches to regex
The task is to find the part of expression, which matches to selected regex and put this part in to value of new field.
The source file is in csv format:
   id;description
   1234;The latitude is 12324.24
   2345;12324.24 this value
   12234;12324.24 is latitude for 12234
   234;No information about latitude

My CSVReader in UpdateRecords:

The "input_schema" is:
 {
 "type": "record",
 "name": "geo_data",
 "fields": [
    {
      "name": "id",
      "type": [
         "int",
         "null"
       ]
    },
    {
      "name": "description",
        "type": [
         "string",
         "null"
       ]
    }
   ]
  }

CSVRecordSetWriter is:

I need to extract "12324.24"-value from "description" and, using UpdateRecord processor, create new field:
"latitude = 12324.24"
I was looking towards matchesRegex. For example:
 /description[matchesRegex(., '(\d+)(\.)(\d+)')]

But it only checks, if the entire expression matches to regex. For example, when "description" includes only "12324.24", matchesRegex works fine, but the field include not only latitude-value.
One important notice:
field value "description" doesn't necessarily contain latitude. So it may include for example: "No information about latitude".
Therefore, substring, substringAfter, substringBefore and similar methods, based on the position (or values) of tokens in text, do not fit for my task.
I tried to use suggested by Endzeit approach:
  replaceRegex(/description, '.*?(\\d+.\\d+).*', '$1')

But it returns the entire value for description fields, which contains matched expression. For example, it returns "12324.24 is latitude" instead of expected: "12324.24"
Or it's better to look forward ExtractText? But problem is that this processor, based on the result of extraction, create only one attribute "latitude" for all records. The possible workaround is to use additionaly SplitText (before extraction) and MergeRecords (after ExtractText). But may be it is somethins overcomplicated?

You are using a "Filter", as described in the "Record Path Guide" inside the documentation.
Your expression /description[matchesRegex(., '(\d+)(\.)(\d+)')] means:

take the field description
only if the fields value (referenced by .)
matches the provided regex.

If the field's value does not match the query, the expression does not resolve to any field (and its value) but null instead.
Just a side note, you can apply such filter expressions to multiple fields simultaneously, e.g. imagine description was an array holding multiple values, your filter could retain only array items that match.
Instead of filtering values, you want to make use of a "Standalone Function" to transform your original input.
The following expression replaceRegex(/description, '.*?(\d+[.]\d+).*', '$1'):

retrieves the value of the field description
matches it against the provided regular expression, and
replaces all matches with the provided substitution

The substitution in turn can reference capture groups, either by index ($1) or by name ${groupName}.
A complete configuration of the UpdateRecord used contains:
{
  "/latitude": "replaceRegex(/description[matchesRegex(., '.*?(\\d+.\\d+).*')], '^.*?(\\d+.\\d+).*$', '$1')",
  "Record Writer": "d79fc7b7-872c-3fd0-8a2a-cf4ff21bfa2e",
  "Record Reader": "44045758-d88e-3c93-ae9f-2173c7860a26",
  "Replacement Value Strategy": "record-path-value"
}

I've uploaded a Flow definition to GitHub that provides a working example. It works both for NiFi 2.0 and 1.22.0 (just needs some property name adjustments in the latter). You can find it here.

I tried your expression. But it returns the entire description-value: "The latitude is 12324.24",  instead of expected "12324.24"

@Jelly That's strange, I've set up an working example Flow in my local NiFi instance. Which version of NiFi are you using?

1.22.0 Nifi-version

I'll try to get an instance of the version running later and get back to you then.

In general, you should consider updating to newer versions of NiFi if feasible. A lot has happened in features, security updates and bug fixes since 1.22.0 which was released 15 months ago; the stable 2.0 release is expected to land in just a few weeks. However, the implementation for replaceRegex hasn't changed in years.

However, I don't think it's related to the version used, seen above. The replaceRegex function returns the value unchanged, when there are no matches. You probably should investigate the regex pattern itself and why it might not work against the value provided.

can it depend on data structure.? My UpdateRecord handle csv file, and CSV_Reader use avro schema:  {
"name": "description",
"type": [
"string",
"null"
]
}

@Jelly Yes, while the implementation of the RecordPath language is agnostic to the readers and writers as well as the format used, the results may vary based on the configuration of the former two. For example, new fields might not get added because the writer uses a schema in which the field is not declared, so it's dropped when writing out the record. Could you update your question with the configuration used for the UpdateRecord processor, your reader and writer used?

I update my question with the configuration of UpdateRecord.  And add some new considerations about ExtractText processor using, as an alternative approach.

@Jelly I've added the link to a working example. You can download the Flow definition and use it to create a ProcessGroup in your instance. In case you don't know, just drag the symbol to create a ProcessGroup and instead of writing a name use the icon on the right to select a file that holds the Flow definition. The example works for both NiFi 2.0 and 1.22.0 (just need to adjust some property names in the latter). I've adjusted the RecordPath expression to disregard Records that do not include a latitude in their description. Hope that helps.

Exelent! it's working! And one notice: if we want to extract from description not only latitude, but also longtitude and the description will be look like (for example):   "latitude is 12.244 and longtitude is 3122.354".   Is it possible extract to 2 different fields both 12.244  and 3122.354 by one regex?

@Jellys Splendid. In general, it's straightforward to add multiple fields at once. Just add another property with the desired field name to the UpdateRecord processor, e.g. /longitude, and provide an appropriate expression.

However, distinguishing between latitude and longitude can be difficult now. Based on your question, there are several ways the description can be formatted. How do you determine which is longitude and which is latitude when both have the same basic format? For example, how do you distinguish longitude from latitude in the description "12.244 3122.354"? Can we assume latitude is declared first always?
